# Youtube-dl takedown, no pafy to stream youtube videos

Tags: python, youtube, vlc, pafy

I began this year with python and i'm doing an music player that streams youtube videos, without downloading them. I'm using tkinter for the gui, vlc to generate a new window and pafy to get the video from youtube. Since the takedown policy of youtube-dl, i have downloaded the 31.10 version of youtube-dlc, but my program says that pafy no longer exists... Is there any way to do the same as above without pafy?

```
def set_media(self):
        url = "youtube url"
        # creating pafy object of the video 
        video = pafy.new(url) 

        # getting best stream 
        best = video.getbest() 

        # creating vlc media player object 
        self.media = vlc.MediaPlayer(best.url)
self.get_media.play()
```

I have tried this:

```
import vlc
import time


url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s5TIulzXoXo"
instance = vlc.Instance()
media = instance.media_new(url)
player = instance.media_player_new()
player.set_media(media)
player.play()

time.sleep(1.5)
duration = player.get_length() / 1000
time.sleep(duration)
```

...but returns 0 and it doesn`t play. It seems that the player can't get the media. What do you think? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the media and play its first subitem.

Try

```
url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s5TIulzXoXo"
instance = vlc.Instance()
media = instance.media_new(url)
media.parse()
subitems = media.subitems()

player = instance.media_player_new()
player.set_media(subitems.first()) // select first subitems
player.play()
```